# disallowed RECEIVE_SMS permission for Flashalerts app in google play

Tags: android, permissions, sms

I have a flash alerts app on google play.
recently google play added some policies which telling us if an app need to use RECEIVE_SMS permission it has to need the permission for core functionality or google will remove the app.
my app use this permission for detect when user get a new SMS so device flash will blink.
i submitted a form but they didn't accept my reason so my question is:
is there any other way to detect when user getting a new SMS without permission?
and if not is there any body here who has a flash alerts app that use RECEIVE_SMS permission and submitted the form and google accepted the reasons?
becuase my app need this permission or it will not work.
what should i do anyone has experience about this subject?

Answer (score 0):

Use a NotificationListenerService. Since you aren't needing the contents of the SMS, listen for the notification produced for an SMS and flash your alert then.

Comment: i use NotificationListenerService for notification alerts but the problem is i want to find a way just for SMS because notification works for all apps and different devices have different default SMS provider apps.

Comment: Offer the user a way to specify in your app then. There isn't a silver bullet answer to be had.

Comment: so there is no other way without permission? i can see lots of flash alerts apps right now in google play with permission. i just wish some one know how they got permission from google to use RECEIVE_SMS